# How to unit testing for modules in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

I have a module(under `/lib` directory) is like

```
module Sbs_score_calculator
  def self.calculate()
     ...
  end
end
```

for calculation. And i want to create unit tests for this module.So i created a test class under `test/unit`

```
require "test/unit"
class SbsCalculateTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  include Sbs_score_calculator

  def test_it
    assert_equals(expected,Sbs_score_calculator.calculate())
  end

end
```

But it gives me error like

```
..../sbs_score_test.rb:5:in `<class:SbsCalculateTest>': uninitialized constant SbsCalculateTest::Sbs_score_calculator (NameError)
    from ..../sbs_score_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy class to include your module in, like so:

```
require "test/unit"

class CalculatorDummy
  include Sbs_score_calculator
end

class SbsCalculateTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_it
    assert_equals(expected, CalculatorDummy.calculate)
  end
end
```

Any reason why `Sbs_score_calculator` isn't named `SbsScoreCalculator` btw?

Comment: naming convention is my bad. But i tried your way and got `NameError: uninitialized constant SbsCalculateTest::Dummy.`

Comment: and also does not sound like the best practice to test a module

Comment: That sounds like you might have used the wrong class name in your assert. It should match whatever class name you gave your dummy class.

Comment: Oh, and if you're just testing class methods on a module you can just skip the dummy class alltogether and just use your original code, but remove the include statement.

Comment: i'm not testing class methods. just module. there must be a way to testing modules seperately. maybe i can change 'there must' to 'i hope there is'.:)

Comment: But you are testing a class method. I don't mean "class method" as being "a method in a class", but "a method defined as self.method_name". Whatever you choose to call those, you should be able to just write `assert_equals(expected, Sbs_score_calculator.calculate)`.

Comment: `assert_equals(expected, Sbs_score_calculator.calculate)` just calling like that is not working and pissing me off